# How to create a multiline chart in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a multiline chart in simple react native mobile application.
I tried various libraries but the multiline chart is not working.
I am new to this. Please help.

Comment: Try react-native-chart-kit (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-chart-kit).
In this example https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit#quick-example pass the values for each line as separate objects inside datasets array.

Comment: Line chart is not working when am passing two objects in the dataset.

Comment: It actually needs to datasets object and not the two data objects. Its working with multiple datasets object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use "react-native-char-kit"
just by providing multiple datasets, you can implement a multiline chart.

```js
<LineChart
    bezier
    withHorizontalLabels={false}
    withVerticalLabels={false}
    data={{
        labels: [' jan', ' feb', ' mar', ' apr', ' june', ' july'],
        datasets: [
                            
                    {
                                data: [10, -4, 6, -8, 80, 20],
                                strokeWidth: 2,
                    },
                    {
                                data: [5,8,6,9,8,2,-2],
                                strokeWidth: 2,
                    },
                ],
        legend: ['car', 'bike'],
        }}
        width={Dimensions.get('window').width - 16}
        height={200}
        chartConfig={{
                        backgroundColor: '#1cc910',
                        backgroundGradientFrom: '#eff3ff',
                        backgroundGradientTo: '#efefef',
                        decimalPlaces: 2,
                        color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
                        style: {
                            borderRadius: 16,
                        },
                    }}
        style={{
                borderRadius: 16,
            }}
                />
```